# access GLB/GLTF outside of loader.load

Tags: javascript, npm, three.js

I would like to use the `dat.gui` package to help me better understand three.js. However, I am not sure how to select the model outside of `loader.load` context.

```js
let model

loader.load('new.glb', function(gltf){
  model = gltf
  scene.add(gltf.scene)
}, undefined, function (error) {
  console.error(error)
})

const options = { wireframe: false}

gui.add(options, 'wireframe').onChange(function(e){
  // cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'wireframe')
  model.material.wireframe = e 
})
```

From my research, this might be due to the fact that the `glb` file is loaded asynchronously?

Anybody know what is happening or how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> From my research, this might be due to the fact that the glb file is loaded asynchronously?

That is correct.

Within the context of the *onChange* handler for the gui, the model is still *undefined*. To edit the model loaded from the gltf file, the change handler needs to be configured within the callback for the loader.

This example creates the gui within the callback for the loader:

```js
let gui;
const options = { wireframe: false };

loader.load('new.glb', function(gltf){
  gui = new dat.GUI();

  scene.add(gltf.scene);
  gui.add(options, "wireframe").onChange(function (e) {
    gltf.material.wireframe = e;
  });
}, undefined, function (error) {
  console.error(error)
})
```

Alternatively, you could define a `render` function and create the gui there:

```
import * as dat from "dat.gui";

let gui;

init();
render();

function init() {
  ...
  gui = new dat.GUI();

  loader.load('new.glb', function(gltf){
    scene.add(gltf.scene);
    render(gltf);
  }, undefined, function (error) {
    console.error(error)
  })
}

function render(gltf) {
  gui.add(options, "wireframe").onChange(function (e) {
    gltf.material.wireframe = e;
  });
}
```

Comment: just gotta test this. hopefully tomorrow. then ill vote/mark as solution. thx for responding <3

Comment: sorry about the delay. for both approaches, the error `Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'wireframe')` is still being thrown, but the UI does show up now at least...

Comment: what might still be causing this issue? (i tried moving around the `onChange` function and the `render(gltf)` call within the `loader.load` to no avail)